# Move mail to another account with mailCore

Tags: mailcore2, mailcore

I trying to move mail from an account to another account with mailCore

I used appendMessageOperationWithFolder to do this.

But when i moved it to new account.

These info: mailed-by, from was changed.

I want mail keep original header info when i move to another account.
How to do this.

I had a test. Apple mail can do this. Does mailCore support us to do this?

```
- (void)sendEmailToFolder:(NSString *) folder flags:(MCOMessageFlag)flags from:(Account *)account rfc822Data:(NSData *)data finishBlock:(void (^)(NSError *error, uint32_t createdUID))finishBlock {
MCOIMAPSession *session = [self imapSession:account];
if (session) {
    [[session appendMessageOperationWithFolder:folder messageData:data flags:flags] start:finishBlock];
} else {
    finishBlock(APIError, -1);
}
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "mailed-by, from was changed"? Also, could you show the code you used?

Comment: Example: In account Mail1 i have an email with from: A@gmail.com, mailed-by: mandrillapp.com. I want move this email to account Mail2. When i moved that email to Mail2, header info was changed to: from: Mail1@gmail.com, mailed-by: gmail.com. How can i keep original header info of that email when i move it to Mail2.

Comment: Could you show the resulting RFC 822 of email? and the difference of the result between Apple mail and MailCore?